# how to set parse duration limit to document object in java

Tags: java, jtidy

I am using Jtidy parser in java.Here is my code...

```
  URL url = new URL("www.yahoo.com");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
  Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
  Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
```

when I come to this statement `Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(in, null);`,it is taking too much time to parse the page, so I want to set the time limit to document object. Please help me, how to set time.

Comment: Are you sure it's the tidying that is slow ? and not the input stream reading ?

Comment: Why not use `conn.setConnectTimeout()` to set timeout?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `java.util.Executors` framework and submit a time-limited task to it.

Here's some code that demonstrates this:

```
// Note that these variables must be declared final to be accessible to task
final InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
final Tidy tidy = new Tidy();

ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
// Create an anonymous class that will be submitted to the service and returns your result
Callable<Document> task = new Callable<Document>() {
    public Document call() throws Exception {
        return tidy.parseDOM(in, null);
    }
};
Future<Document> future = service.submit(task);
// Future.get() offers a timed version that may throw a TimeoutException
Document doc = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```